# How do I import a library from the lib folder in my web app?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

My folder structure looks like this:

```
lib\
    my_library.dart
web\
    index.html
    main.dart
pubspec.yaml
```

In `main.dart`, I'm currently importing `my_library.dart` (which has `library my_library` at the top) by doing:

```
import '../lib/my_library.dart';
```

This works fine. However, it feels a bit fragile to have this relative path. I read in the [Pub Package Layout Conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) that I can probably use `import 'package:blah'`; it says:

> When you use libraries from within your own package, even code in src, you can (and should) still use "package:" to import them

So, I tried changing my code to this:

```
import 'package:my_library.dart';
```

However, in Chrome Dev Editor I get:

> Target or URI does not exist: 'package:grid_data.dart'

and in Dartium I get:

> GET http:// 127.0.0.1:51792/MyProject/web/packages/my_library.dart 404 (Not Found)

What's the correct way to import something from my `lib` folder from other dart files in my project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the package name

```dart
import 'package:my_project/my_library.dart';
```

The `package:` part in your import statement references the packages folder in your `my_project` package (the folder that contains the `pubspec.yaml`. The remainder of the import statement is the path to the file you want to import.
You can browse through the folders and files in this packages folder in DartEditor or a file manager to see exactly how the files are organized.
This folder also contains a symlink named `my_project` which points to your `my_project/lib` folder.

Comment: Doh! Seems kinda obvious now I look in packages :)

Comment: You should be aware that this doesn't work the same way in HTML. There is no `package:`. You need to navigate to the package top folder and than down through the `packages` folder. From `web/index.html` this would be `../packages/my_project/my_library.css` (don't mix `package:` with `package*s*/`

Comment: Yep; that makes sense (since one is a path for the browser to interpret, and the other is a Dart import thing!)

Comment: Dart is resolved at build time (pub serve/pub build) and HTML is resolved by the browser.